# Python code to authenticate to website, navigate through links and download files

Tags: python

I'm looking something which could be interesting to you as well. 
I'm developing a feature using **Python**, which should be able to authenticate (using userid/password and/or with other preferred authentication methods) and connect to specify website, navigate through the website and download the file under a specific option.
Later I have to write the schedules on developed code and automate it.

Did anyone come across such scenario and developed the code in **python**?
Please suggest if any python libraries are there.

What I have achieved right now is:

I can download file with specific URL.

I know how to authenticate and download the file.

I'm able to pull the links from the specific website.

This is something we could achieve using selenium, but I want to write in **Python**.

Comment: What is the problem? What you have seems like what you want?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't think your question is specific enough to be on topic here. You should visit the [help] and read the section on [MVCE]

Comment: I think I see the problem... You're missing a specific question.  Please see [ask] and refine your question.

Comment: I'm developing a feature, which should be able to authenticate, navigate through the website and download the file under a specific option.
Later I have to write the schedules on developed code and automate it.

Comment: Questions ends with a question mark.  That's a mission statement.  Have you taken a [tour] yet to see what sort of posts are considered on topic around here? I would encourage you to do so to understand why your post is currently frowned upon.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to sell something or asking ä someone to invest in your idea, not asking for help.

Comment: This is a requirement I have and I'm really looking for help.

Comment: @DattaTembare If you want help, start by reading the links that have been provided earlier in the comments. [Take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 5 days of research, I found what I wanted. Your `urlLogin` and `urlAuth` could be same, its totally depends on what action taken on Login button or form action. I used crome inspect option to findout the actual `GET` or `POST` request used on the portal.

Here is the answer of my own question-->

```
import requests

urlLogin = 'https://example.com/jsp/login.jsp'
urlAuth = 'https://example.com/CheckLoginServlet'
urlBd = 'https://example.com/jsp/batchdownload.jsp'
payload = {
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password"
}

# Session will be closed at the end of with block
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.get(urlLogin)
    headers = s.cookies.get_dict()
    print(f"Session cookies {headers}")
    r1 = s.post(urlAuth, data=payload, headers=headers)
    print(f'MainFrame text:::: {r1.status_code}')  #200

    r2 = s.post(urlBd, data=payload)
    print(f'MainFrame text:::: {r2.status_code}')  #200
    print(f'MainFrame text:::: {r2.text}')  #page source

    # 3. Again cookies will be used through session to access batch download page
    r2 = s.post(config['access-url'])
    print(f'Batch Download status:::: {r2.status_code}')  #200
    source_code = r2.text
    # print(f'Batch Download source:::: {source_code}')
```

Comment: Here header is optional, code could be 
 `r1 = s.post(urlAuth, data=payload)`