# Is there any way for make a log in website by python

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, web-crawler, urllib

I want to make a Login, and then crawling this site.

I made a login by python so that I have to get salaries for every class(level of employee).

Login url =  https://www.jobplanet.co.kr/users/sign_in
every class salary url = https://www.jobplanet.co.kr/companies/20575/salaries/

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib, http.cookiejar
cj = http.cookiejar.LWPCookieJar()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj)) 
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

params = urllib.parse.urlencode({"mode":"login", "user_email":"*******", "user_password":"******"})
params = params.encode('utf-8')
req = urllib.request.Request("https://www.jobplanet.co.kr/users/sign_in", headers=headers)
rej = urllib.request.Request("https://www.jobplanet.co.kr/companies/20575/salaries/", headers=headers)
res = opener.open(rej)

html = res.read()
```

Comment: Not an expert on this but, it seems to me you are not using params anywhere after encoding them in utf-8?

Comment: Here is the code .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53192938/python-code-to-authenticate-to-website-navigate-through-links-and-download-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find out the `urlLogin`, `aurlAuth` and `urlBd` (urlbody) from which you want to pull the source code.
You can use Chrome or Firefox devtools (F12 key on windows).

You have `urlLogin` but `aurlAuth` could be different, use browser's devtool and do actual login, when you hit Login button you will see requests details in network tab. (Don't forget to click **Network** checkbox)

```
import requests

urlLogin = 'https://example.com/jsp/login.jsp'
urlAuth = 'https://example.com/CheckLoginServlet'
urlBd = 'https://example.com/jsp/batchdownload.jsp'
payload = {
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password"
}

# Session will be closed at the end of with block
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.get(urlLogin)
    headers = s.cookies.get_dict()
    print(f"Session cookies {headers}")
    # Use headers if you want to append your own headers to default
    r1 = s.post(urlAuth, data=payload, headers=headers)
    # Here header is optional, code could be 
    # r1 = s.post(urlAuth, data=payload) 
    print(f'MainFrame text:::: {r1.status_code}')  #200

    r2 = s.post(urlBd, data=payload)
    print(f'MainFrame text:::: {r2.status_code}')  #200
    print(f'MainFrame text:::: {r2.text}')  #page source

    # 3. Again cookies will be used through session to access batch download page
    r2 = s.post(config['access-url'])
    print(f'Batch Download status:::: {r2.status_code}')  #200
    source_code = r2.text
    # print(f'Batch Download source:::: {source_code}')
```

Comment: thanks for help. But, I think It doesn`t work at this site. Could you retry on that site by your facebook account?   I want to get information from salaries page (https://www.jobplanet.co.kr/companies/20575/salaries/) with log in information...